# Dagger2 in Eclipse not generating classes

Tags: eclipse, mortar, dagger-2

I'm trying to set up a new App with Mortar. For this I am trying to build the [mortar HelloWorld projects](https://github.com/square/mortar/). I have to use Eclipse because Android Studio does not support native debugging (I prefer Android Studio and Gradle much more).

- The `mortar-helloworld` example with Dagger1 works in Eclipse (Ant) when I set up Dagger1 like described [here](http://scouse.com/adding-dagger-to-an-android-eclipse-project/)
- The `mortar-hellodagger2` example works when I build it with Maven
- However when I try to build the `mortar-hellodagger2` example with Eclipse (Ant) I get a `ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mortar.Dagger_Main_Component`.

I did set up Dagger2 like Dagger1 and put the libs in the folders like this:

```
libs: dagger-2.0, javax.inject-1
compile-libs: dagger-compiler-with-dependencies-2.0.jar
```

Has anyone successfully set up Eclipse with Dagger2?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable annotation processing in Eclipse. Right click on the project > Properties > Java Compiler > Annotation Processing > Enable ...

Comment: It is enabled... I said Dagger1 works which it only does when Annotation Processing is enabled. Dagger2 doesn't work even with Annotation Processing.